# Turing machine to compute $⌈\log_2n⌉$ with 1 tape and unary input/output

Tags: turing-machines

I'm trying to figure out how to make the action table for a Turing Machine computing $⌈\log_{2}(n)⌉$. The input and output shall be unary (meaning $3$ should represent $111$). I can only deal with 1 tape.

Also, I would prefer having 7 transition states, 1 final state, 24 actions and 5 symbols, but any other numbers are fine too. At the end of the computation, the TM head should be at the 1st $1$ from the left, of the output.

For $⌈\log_{2}(0)⌉$, I would like to have the symbol $N$ on the tape.

I would also like an easy-to-understand explanation, if possible.

Comment: I answered that question here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/132571/create-a-turing-machine-for-log-base-2-of-n/135717#135717
You just need a little modification for the entry $0$ and for the head position. Also, your numbers are oddly specific…

Comment: The thing is, I need an efficient Turing machine...

Comment: Less states does not mean more efficient. What you should look at is the asymptotic number of transitions.

Comment: oh okay. Btw, my blank symbol is $^$ and not $#$. Plus in your simulator, I can see $#$ and " " are 2 different symbols, since $#$ sometimes changes into " ". Why's that? My Turing machine basically needs to have something like $...^^^111111^^^...$ with the $...$ representing $^$'s. Does your simulation do the same thing? And is there an alternative way that doesn't deal with binary representation?

Comment: The way you write the blank symbol is not important, you just need to adapt to your needs. Same thing for the simulator, I did not create the simulator, only the simulation, and I adapted my TM to the simulator. I don’t know if there is a way not to use binary representation, but I find it the simplest way to understand.

Comment: Oh okay... So what's the difference between the # and the _ symbol in your action table? Does it mean the same thing? Also, I don't see any $ sign in your simulation.

Comment: In my answer, the blank symbol is $\#$, and the separator symbol is $\$$. In the simulation, the blank symbol is $\_$ and the separator is $\#$. That may be confusing, but as I said, this is not my simulator, and I wrote the answer before creating the simulation.

Comment: ohh okay Now I get it!!! But you could've used $ for separator in the sim as well right? Otherwise it'd get confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach is *repeated halving*.

Remove a single 1 from the input (if you fail, output N).
Then go over the tape in passes. Each pass deletes every other 1 encountered (starting with the first). The number of passes required to delete all 1s is $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$. You can count the number of passes as you go.

For example, suppose that $n=6$:

```
111111       Delete the first 1
b11111       Delete every other 1
2b1b1b       Delete every other 1
22bb1b       Delete every other 1
222bbb       Convert back to 1
111bbb       Done
```

The number of passes is $3 = \lceil \log_2 n \rceil$.

Comment: Wdym by "go over the tape in passes"?

Comment: Go over the tape once, then go over the tape again, and so on. Each time you go over the tape is a "pass".

Comment: Okay so, where did the 2 come from? And wdym by every other 1? If we Delete every other 1 from step 2, don't we end up in all blanks?

Comment: The 2 is a counter that counts the number of passes. It's easier to use a different symbol in order to avoid a mixup with the 1s, though perhaps it can be avoided.

Comment: You do end up in all blanks, and that's on purpose. Take a look at my example. At this point, I suggest spending an hour (at least) trying to understand the algorithm and why it works.

Comment: I figured it out and it works for probably every number!! Thank you!!!! One question though: What if we were using binary input and unary output? What difference would it make to this approach??

Comment: Binary input is much easier, since after removing the leading zeroes, the length of the input is $\lceil \log_2(n+1) \rceil$.

Comment: wdym? Please can you give me an example?

Comment: You can try your own examples.

Comment: Okay, so example, I have the number $10111$. How do I convert that?

Comment: I suggest spending a few hours in the matter.

Comment: If the length of the input is $\lceil \log_2(n+1) \rceil$, then how do we obtain $\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil$ ?

Comment: One way is subtracting one. Another way is identifying the unique case when these two expressions are not the same, namely, when $n$ is a power of 2, a property which is easy to recognize.

Comment: Wdym subtracting one? $\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil$ is not the same as $\lceil \log_2(n+1) \rceil-1$ right?

Comment: Subtract one from $n$.