# How to implement a Turing Machine that calculates log base 2 of n where n is a natural number and output in a unary format?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

How would you construct a Turing Machine that calculates log2(n)?

The process must take in an input such as 4 and output the result in a unary format such as a 11 (11 = 2 in unary)?

In the final output tape, the tape should only contain blank symbols followed by a consecutive number of 1's from the final head position.

Many Thanks

Comment: What is the format of the input? If it is binary there is not much to do, just turn all characters into $1$s and remove the last one.

Comment: The format is a natural number but in unary, so if the user wants an input of 4 they will use 1111.

Comment: Then this question has been answered here before, if I remember correctly. Essentially pass over the input replacing each pair of $1$s by a single one. Every time you finish going over the input, write a $1$ in the output. Repeat with the modified input until it dissapears.

Comment: Popular question, it has been asked before, earlier today actually: [Turing machine to compute ⌈log2(n)⌉ with 1 tape and unary input/output](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/135816/4287). And for the answer, see @plop's comment for a excellent suggestion.

Comment: That is much more efficient than the method I am currently trying to pursue, thanks Plop!